# Command-line web request client that outputs content and return non-zero exit status if error 404/etc

Tags: gratis, linux, http

I need a Linux command to launch an HTTP request, and:

- dump the HTTP response (content, not headers) on the terminal standard output
- return an command error status of 0 if the request went well (ended up with HTTP code 200 OK), and non-zero in all other cases (404, 500, connection failed, etc)

Gratis, needs to work on most Linux distributions, bonus for Mac.

[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) does not seem to be able to do that, as its `--fail` switch prevents HTTP output.

Comment: Raw idea: a simple Bash wrapper. Capture output into a file, check for HTTP status, then act accordingly (`cat` the file and `rc=0`, or simply `rc>0` otherwise)?

Comment: Upvoted. Just don't forget to delete your `$HEADERS` when done, or after a while you've got plenty of temp files :)

Comment: Anytime! I've solved a lot of similar issues this way – a few lines Bash can do a lot. And if it's a one-liner, it often ends up as alias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small bash wrapper does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Perform a web request, dump content, and exit with relevant exit code

# Take URL as command-line argument
URL=$1

# Launch HTTP request
HEADERS=`mktemp`
curl --dump-header $HEADERS $URL

# Read the first header (example: HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
HEADER=`head -n 1 $HEADERS`

# Remove temporary file
rm $HEADERS

# Return success if HTTP code OK, or failure for any other HTTP code
if [[ $HEADER == *" 200 "* ]]; then
  exit 0
else
  exit 1
fi
```

It requires [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) and [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)).

License: Public domain